# Is there an app that can transmit mic input to bluetooth devices?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, bluetooth, 17.10, microphone

Since I have a lot of different formats of audio It sometimes becomes a hassle when listening to music when I have to bring my aux cord with me into the shower.  I am asking about the bluetooth option because then if I were to have,say, a desktop tape deck I can plug it in via the mic cable and transmit it to my beats pill xl.  Anyways thanks for further help...regards,
Thomas

Comment: See the duplicate. You can use the _loopback_ module for pulseaudio, to redirect audio.

Comment: Is there a GUI for this though?  I'm good with command line but it would be nice to be able to do this with a GUI so I could do this with a couple clicks.

Comment: I am not aware of any GUI to do this, no.